# Removing question mark ? from subfolder URL in htacces wp

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a problem and can't find any solutions on the net.

My site keeps generating `/blog/?` URLs and I can't seem to find the way to get rid of them with htaccess.

All of these URLs are also creating a duplicate content problems in Webmaster tools.

I found many answers were others have these type of issues:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/?...
```

But not when it involves sub folder like this:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/blog/?
```

I have tried modifying the rules suggested with adding `/blog/` but nothing worked.

Could you please help with a rule that will solve this problem in htaccess file as I am tired redirecting new appearing URLs every week.

Comment: We can't do much without seeing your .htaccess to see if there is anything on it that would result on that issue. [**You can use the Edit link above to update your question with more information or click here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18559457/edit)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\?(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

You'd put those rules in the htaccess file in your document root.